# como puedo hacer sumar los numero de una lista de n dígitos dados

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Ejemplo:**

```
lista = [57463, 9182, 8127]
```

yo quiero hacer la suma de cada uno es decir:
5 + 7+ 4 + 6 + 3 =
y saber su resultado y así mismo con los otros ese es objetivo pero lo que quiero hacer es esto

```
num = input('Escribir 4 serie de numeros')
lista = list(num)
n1 = lent(num[0])
n2 = lent(num[1])
n3 = lent(num[2])
n4 = lent(num[3])
```

y aqui ya no se que hacer quiero que me pida la serie de numeros y poder ver cual hace la suma mas grande

Comment: Podrías dar una demostración de que sos parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda por favor? De lo contrario, probablemente tu pregunta no sea bien recibida y termine cerrada y/o con votos negativos.

Comment: `print([sum(int(x) for x in str(y)) for y in lista])`

Comment: evidentemente no buscás demasiado y no probás lo que haces ¿lent?

Comment: `list(num)` convierte todo en una lista de caracteres, no una lista de enteros.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo resuelve:

```py
lista = []

for _ in range(4): 
  n = int(input("ingresa una serie de nros: "))
  lista.append(n)

mayor = 0
mayor_real = 0

def suma_digitos(numero):
  suma = 0
  
  for digito in str(numero): 
    suma += int(digito)

  return suma 

for item in lista:
  if suma_digitos(item) > mayor: 
    mayor = suma_digitos(item)
    mayor_real = item 
  
print(f"El nro que tiene la mayor suma de dígitos es: {mayor_real}")
```

Básicamente empiezo cambiando la forma de cómo entran las series de números, la acoplo a 4 porque es lo que dice tu código; luego, establezco dos variables:

- `mayor` que hace referencia a la suma mayor actual.
- `mayor_real` que hace referencia al valor del item que se iterará.

Posterior a ello defino una función que lo que hace básicamente es la suma de dígitos de un número, lo transforma a string para suma caracter por caracter y como sabemos que cada uno de estos es un digito, solo lo transformo a entero con `int()`.

Al final, se puede ser un `for` que lo que hace es iterar item por item (series de nros ingresados) y aplica la suma de dígitos a cada uno, si la suma resulta ser mayor entonces se establece como suma 'dominante' a la actual en la variable `mayor` y la serie como `mayor_real` (que es el valor final que deseamos).